# Myeclipse is throwing some error when i debug server

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

```
When i try debug server . Myeclipse is showing some error.
Perspective switch job has encountered a problem.An internal error has occurred.
java.lang.NullPointerException.
And after that it hangs.
Here is the attatched error message pic.
```

[image]

And here is the log.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-01-30 15:22:34.684
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onDeactivate(Perspective.java:1120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3704)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$16(WorkbenchPage.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$19.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3812)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveBarContributionItem.select(PerspectiveBarContributionItem.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveBarContributionItem$1.widgetSelected(PerspectiveBarContributionItem.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.genuitec.pulse.eclipse.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:110)
```

Comment: Look in the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory for a more detailed message.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem finally? or did you have to re-install everything?

Comment: Having same issue here.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677604/eclipse-luna-gives-nullpointerexception-when-debugging-hits-a-breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

Seems as your MyEclipse installation is broken. You should reinstall it. In my experience such internal errors cannot be fixed which an acceptable effort.

Answer (score 1):

Before reinstalling, try adding

-clean

to the top of your myeclipse.ini file (it's in the same folder as the myelipse.exe file). Remove it after the next launch, as it slows down startup.